# Passwordless su in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, password, authentication, sudo, su

I've run into a dilemma while migrating a Hadoop installation from Oracle Enterprise Linux to Ubuntu. The prior developer put the following command into `rc.local` within OEL:

```
su reporter -c "cd /path/to/directorywithscript && bash runwebserver.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1&"
```

I need the above webserver to automatically start (and stop) in Ubuntu as the specified `reporter` user. (The automation stuff is ***much*** less important than getting this script to properly run as the `reporter` user, but is a "nice to have" feature.)

This process needs to start last, as I still need to configure a couple of other Hadoop-related scripts to automatically start before this one (the webserver resides in the Hadoop filesystem, which doesn't get mounted until after you're in the OS). Every time I issue the `su` command I get asked for a password. This occurs regardless of which user is currently "active" and wasn't a problem in OEL since the Root user is actually used. Here is my current attempt at a /etc/sudoers file, but it's still not working (I'm unsure if the changes I made at the bottom are correct):

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command after they have
# provided their password
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
user3 ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/bin/su
user2 ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/bin/su
user1 ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/bin/su
reporter ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/bin/su
```

This is a duplicate of a thread I posted over at UbuntuForums.org (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12040341#post12040341), but I'm getting desperate for an answer =P. Please note that my Linux knowledge is still weak (I knew almost no Linux before this project was dropped in my lap). Any help is *greatly* appreciated as this is currently a major stumbling block!

Thanks,
-Snipe

Answer (score 2):

*Your current edits to `/etc/sudoers` effectively let `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, and `reporter` perform any action as `root` (since running `su` lets you become `root`)! You almost certainly do not want this. And this doesn't help your current problem at all, because you don't want those users to run something with an alternate identity, you want `root` to run something with an alternate identity. Before proceeding, I recommend getting rid of those lines from `/etc/sudoers` (edit it with `visudo` of course) unless you're absolutely sure that's what you want.*

If you're a non-`root` user and you run this, you will always be asked for a password:

```
su reporter -c "cd /path/to/directorywithscript && bash runwebserver.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1&"
```

But when `root` runs that, it should simply succeed (assuming it worked before on Oracle Enterprise Server and the only relevant difference is that `root` login is disabled on Ubuntu).

When you put that line in `rc.local`, in any GNU/Linux distribution, including Ubuntu, it is run as `root`. It should just work. When you run it from the command-line, it will not work. But in `rc.local`, it should just work.

If you want to test it from the command-line, give yourself a `root` shell of the kind pretty similar to `rc.local`'s environment:

```
sudo -i
```

(This simulates an initial `root` login shell. Normally, for a `root` shell, use `sudo -s`. And of course, to run a command `...` with `sudo`, just use `sudo ...`.)

`su -c` and `sudo` take different syntax, so if you did want to make that command use `sudo` instead of `su`, you'd have to make additional changes. The easiest way is probably:

```
sudo -u reporter bash -c "cd /path/to/directorywithscript && ./runwebserver.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1&"
```

However, I emphasize that **you do not need to convert `su` commands to `sudo` for them to run properly out of `rc.local`**.

In Ubuntu, unlike Oracle Enterprise Server, logging in as `root` is disabled by default (and you almost certainly shouldn't enable it). But `su` still works when run *by* `root`. `su` also works for a non-`root` user changing identity to another non-`root` user.

**If you have this line in `rc.local` and it's not working, the reason isn't issues of `sudo` vs. `su`. In that case, something else is going wrong. For us to troubleshoot it, you'd have to provide the contents of `runwebserver.sh`.**

Finally, please note that `bash runwebserver.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1&` is rather inelegant. It's simpler to understand (and, much less importantly, looks nicer) to use `bash runwebserver.sh &>> /dev/null`. You said this runs last in `rc.local`, so you don't have to use `&` to background it.

However, you should consider if you really want to suppress *standard error* as well as *standard output* (as you're currently doing). Presumably if something is written to standard error then it's either important or can be suppressed by altering your web server's verbosity settings.

Comment: Looks like the sudoers file I created is working as was mentioned in my original UbuntuForums.org post. The following code successfully changes users without a password prompt:

[CODE]sudo su reporter[/CODE]

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to just type "su reporter" while avoiding a password prompt?

Comment: Wow, thank you for the crazy in-depth answer Eliah! I'll thoroughly read this over and respond appropriately in the morning as I need to leave work right now =/.

Comment: @Sniperm4n The `reporter` line in `sudoers` is not why it is working, and should be removed. Presumably `reporter` is a deliberately limited non-`root` user that runs your web server with deliberately reduced permissions. Assuming this is the case, `reporter` should *definitely* not be able to run `/bin/su` as `root` (as you currently have configured in `sudoers`). Furthermore, any administrator on your system can already use `sudo` to run that or any other command as `root`; there's probably no good reason for your `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` entries either.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your in-depth responses! Unfortunately, the project has been terminated (with the finish line in sight) and I can't test this any further. Yay for corporate B.S.! =/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be asked for a password you will have to use to execute su as root,
so you will have to use:

```
sudo su reporter -c "cd /path/to/directorywithscript && bash runwebserver.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1&"
```

However, i think what you are trying to do is a realy bad idea, you are allowing every user to log in as anyone else, including root.

Comment: This line is in `rc.local` and runs as `root` already, so it's unnecessary (and does nothing differently) to put `sudo` in front of it there. For testing the command, this makes sense, although it's not ideal because it tests the command with the current non-`root` user's environment. (See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/153331/22949) for details.) **You're quite right that the current `sudoers` configuration seems to let every user become root, though, and that this is bad. At least `reporter` is presumably not an administrator, and intentionally so.**

Comment: All of the users on the system are admins actually lol. The fortunate thing about this is that we're much less concerned about security due to the fact this is a pre-production cluster. I'll re-read and ponder your initial answer tomorrow morning! =)